# Activity binding a Service throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-service, android-service-binding

In my Activity I have instance variables `LocalBinder mBinder ;ServiceConnection mConnection; and`boolean mBound;`

In `onCreate` I instantiate a `ServiceConnection` and set it to `mConnection` like this:

```
mConnection=new ServiceConnection()
{
   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName class name,IBinder service){
     Log.d(TAG,"Service connected");
     mBinder=(LocalService.LocalBinder)service;
 }
```

And I set mBinder to null in `onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)`

The problem seems to be that the call to bind the a service using:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LocalService.class);
   bindService(intent,mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

never occurs...thus ServiceConnection is never called...and when I use a public method in the `LocalBinder` class it throws an exception because binder is null.

I have a non-null `ServiceConnection` object and am using the right context.The Activity is launched on app start.The `LocalBinder` is as you might have guessed a static inner class of `LocalService`.

The Local Service looks like this:

```
 static  class LocalBinder
{
     public int getRandomNumber()
    {
         return (int)(Math.random()*100);
    }
 }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
  {
     LocalBinder binder=new LocalBinder();
      return binder;
     }
```

The service starts when I implement `onStartCommand` and `startService(intent);` but it won't bind...Service Connected will not display even though `bindService` returns true...thus the IBinder is not passed to the Activity causing a NullPointerException

Comment: when do you try to access mBinder?

Comment: In `onResume` like `mBinder.getRandomNumber();` in a for loop,this is where the exception shows up in LogCat

Comment: try to Log.d return value of bindService()

Comment: The value returned by `bindService` is `true`,I understand that the bind service returns and then the `ServiceConnection` is called with IBinder

Comment: and yet you dont see "Service connected" in the logcat?

Comment: Yes,exactly my point...

Comment: hmm, strange, does startService work at all?

Comment: Using `startService` before binding it does not work either,do I absolutely need to implement `onStartCommand` for bound service

Comment: but is service started or not? was onStartCommand being called?

Comment: Yes,the service started...it just won't bind

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to create a ServiceConnection()--rather, I think you implement the ServiceConnection interface in your Activity, then pass the Activity in bindService:

```
public class MyClientActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LocalService.class), this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Service connected");
        mBinder=(LocalService.LocalBinder)service;
    }
```

You'll also need to implement onServiceDisconnected().  Hope that helps.